Improving the output of pseudocode C++ code from IDA Pro
I have some specific questions and some general ones about reverse-engineering a dynamic shared library via IDA Pro 8.3:

If I know the compiler used and compiler flags used (via readelf --debug-dump), can I provide more info to IDA Pro to generate better/more accurate pseudo C++ code?  For example, readelf --debug-dump gives me GNU C++ 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) -msse4 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -O2 -std=c++11 -fPIC and GNU C++ 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) -msse4 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -O2 -std=c++11 -fPIC -fpermissive.  It seems like the best I can tell IDA Pro via Options->Compiler->GNU C++.

I also selected "clang" as the source parser and supplied with -target x86_64-pc-linux -msse4 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -O2 -std=c++11 -fPIC, and 4.8.5's header files from CentOS.  But the output doesn't change much.  Mostly the comments changed from //weak to //idb, which I don't know what it means.  I was hoping the vtable "reference"s in the pseudo code (as the tutorial seems to suggest), but they remains there.

What other things I can do to make IDA Pro to generate better/more accurate pseudo C++ code? e.g. plug-ins, or?



What kinds of changes did you want to see in the output? Which tutorial are you talking about in your question?
